# Keyboard on new notebook works only until typing in the Windows account-password

Tags: windows-8, laptop, keyboard, windows-8.1

I'm setting up my g/f's new Acer notebook (coming pre-installed with Windows 8.1) via TeamViewer. For some reasons the internal keyboard completely stopped working. It works until she types in the password for her Windows-account but then nothing but the Windows-key (to activate the tile-view) works.
The trackpad works without flaws.

I can use my own keyboard via teamviewer.
It looks like a hardware-problem but since the keyboard works until she's inside of Windows 8.1 this is just strange.

Does anyone have a slight clue what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you by some chance enabled TV's "Disable remote input" option?

Answer (score 0):

Try as an experiment, bypassing Windows 8 by going in to the restore facility. Not sure of your exact model, but the following works on some Acers :

1 Check to see if Acer disk-to-disk recovery is enabled or not.
2 Make sure the D2D Recovery setting in Main is Enabled.
3 Exit the BIOS utility and save changes. The system will reboot.
Note: To activate the BIOS utility, press (F2) during POST.
To start the recovery process:
1 Restart the system.
2 While the Acer logo is showing, press (Alt) + (F10) at the same time to enter the recovery process.

You don't want to actually go ahead and do the recovery, but just find out if the keyboard works at all while you are in there.

I expect it will, so we can then figure out what Windows is doing.
Which happened first - keyboard stopped working, or, installed Teamviewer ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's working while she types in the password and stops working post that, it's definitely not a hardware problem. Seems like some program is stopping it to work. Try these:

1. Try to boot your g/f's system in safe mode and check whether the keyboard is working there or not.
2. If the laptop has a restore point, try restoring it. It's a way to undo system changes to your computer without affecting your personal files, such as e‑mail, documents, or photos.
3. Try to re-install the drivers of laptop's internal keyboard by going into the device manager.